# Need to speed up very slow loop for image manipulation on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am currently completing a program in Pyhton (3.6) as per internal requirement. As part of it, I am having to loop through a colour image (3 bytes per pixel, R, G & B) and distort the image  pixel by pixel.

I have the same code in other languages (C++, C#), and non-optimized code executes in about two seconds, while optimized code executes in less than a second. By non-optimized code I mean that the matrix multiplication is performed by a 10 line function I implemented. The optimized version just uses external libraries for multiplication.

In Python, this code takes close to 300 seconds. I can´t think of a way to vectorize this logic or speed it up, as there are a couple of "if"s inside the nested loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np

#for test purposes:
#roi = rect.rect(0, 0, 1200, 1200)
#input = DCImage.DCImage(1200, 1200, 3)
#correctionImage = DCImage.DCImage(1200,1200,3)
#siteToImage= np.zeros((3,3), np.float32)
#worldToSite= np.zeros ((4, 4))
#r11 = r12 = r13 = r21 = r22 = r23 = r31 = r32 = r33 = 0.0
#xMean = yMean = zMean = 0 
#tx = ty = tz = 0
#epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps
#fx = fy = cx = cy = k1 = k2 = p1 = p2 = 0


for i in range (roi.x, roi.x + roi.width):
    for j in range (roi.y , roi.y + roi.height):
        if ( (input.pixels [i] [j] == [255, 0, 0]).all()):
            #Coordinates conversion
            siteMat = np.matmul(siteToImage, [i, j, 1])
            world =np.matmul(worldToSite, [siteMat[0], siteMat[1], 0.0, 1.0])

            xLocal = world[0] - xMean
            yLocal = world[1] - yMean
            zLocal = z_ortho - zMean
            #From World to camera
            xCam = r11*xLocal + r12*yLocal + r13*zLocal + tx
            yCam = r21*xLocal + r22*yLocal + r23*zLocal + ty
            zCam = r31*xLocal + r32*yLocal + r33*zLocal + tz
            if (zCam > epsilon or zCam < -epsilon):
                xCam = xCam / zCam
                yCam = yCam / zCam

            #// DISTORTIONS                           
            r2 = xCam*xCam + yCam*yCam
            a1 = 2*xCam*yCam
            a2 = r2 + 2*xCam*xCam
            a3 = r2 + 2*yCam*yCam
            cdist = 1 + k1*r2 + k2*r2*r2
            u = int((xCam * cdist + p1 * a1 + p2 * a2) * fx + cx + 0.5)
            v = int((yCam * cdist + p1 * a3 + p2 * a1) * fy + cy + 0.5)

            if (u>=0 and u<correctionImage.width and v>=0 and v < correctionImage.height):
                input.pixels [i] [j] =  correctionImage.pixels [u][v]
```

Comment: Rather than edit directly with numpy, you could use libraries to manipulate images. For example [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). It's generally faster to use them.

Comment: Using an image manipulation library is definitely the way to go. Or you can just write that in C++ and use bindings to use it on Python.

Comment: The for loop is an algorithm we tend to use in C#, and it is not in any image processing library (I used OpenCV-Python for the rest of the application, since it had all the necessary functions). Writing it in C++ and calling the function is the alternative if I can not make it go fast in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You normally vectorize this kind of thing by making a displacement map.

Make a complex image where each pixel has the value of its own coordinate, apply the usual math operations to compute whatever transform you want, then apply the map to your source image.

For example, in [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) you might write:

```
import sys
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])

# this makes an image where pixel (0, 0) (at the top-left) has value [0, 0],
# and pixel (image.width, image.height) at the bottom-right has value
# [image.width, image.height]
index = pyvips.Image.xyz(image.width, image.height)

# make a version with (0, 0) at the centre, negative values up and left,
# positive down and right
centre = index - [image.width / 2, image.height / 2]

# to polar space, so each pixel is now distance and angle in degrees
polar = centre.polar()

# scale sin(distance) by 1/distance to make a wavey pattern
d = 10000 * (polar[0] * 3).sin() / (1 + polar[0])

# and back to rectangular coordinates again to make a set of vectors we can
# apply to the original index image
distort = index + d.bandjoin(polar[1]).rect()

# distort the image
distorted = image.mapim(distort)

# pick pixels from either the distorted image or the original, depending on some
# condition
result = (d.abs() > 10 or image[2] > 100).ifthenelse(distorted, image)

result.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

That's just a silly wobble pattern, but you can swap it for any distortion you want. Then run as:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./wobble.py ~/pics/horse1920x1080.jpg x.jpg
54572:0.31
```

300ms and 55MB of memory on this two-core, 2015 laptop to make:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Will give it a go shortly and post results back.

Answer (score 1):

After much testing, the only way to speed the function without writing it in C++ was dissassembling it and vectorizing it. The way to do it in this particular instance is to create an array with the valid indexes at the beginning of the funcion and use them as tuples to index the final solution.

```py
subArray[roi.y:roi.y+roi.height,roi.x:roi.x+roi.width,] = input.pixels[roi.y:roi.y+roi.height,roi.x:roi.x+roi.width,]

#Calculate valid XY indexes
y_index, x_index = np.where(np.all(subArray== np.array([255,0,0]), axis=-1))

#....
#do stuff
#....

#Join result values with XY indexes
ij_xy = np.column_stack((i, j, y_index, x_index))

#Only keep valid ij values
valids_ij_xy = ij_xy [(ij_xy [:,0] >= 0) & (ij_xy [:,0] < correctionImage.height) & (ij_xy [:,1] >= 0) & (ij_xy [:,1] < correctionImage.width)]

#Assign values
input.pixels [tuple(np.array(valids_ij_xy [:,2:]).T)] = correctionImage.pixels[tuple(np.array(valids_ij_xy [:,:2]).T)]
```